Cannot install pendulum 3.0.0 on Raspberry Pi Zero 2
I am trying to install the azure-identity and msgraph-sdk packages through pip on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 with Raspbian OS (Debian 32-bit) installed. However, during installation, building the wheel for pendulum 3.0.0 fails (I had to install Rust and Cargo before it even attempts to build the wheel) with a rather peculiar error:
  × Building wheel for pendulum (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      Running `maturin pep517 build-wheel -i /usr/bin/python3 --compatibility off`
       Building a mixed python/rust project
       Found pyo3 bindings
       Found CPython 3.9 at /usr/bin/python3
         Compiling target-lexicon v0.12.6
         Compiling python3-dll-a v0.2.9
         Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
         Compiling libc v0.2.139
         Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.51
         Compiling once_cell v1.17.1
         Compiling pyo3-build-config v0.19.1
         Compiling quote v1.0.23
         Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.6
         Compiling syn v1.0.109
         Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
         Compiling cc v1.0.79
         Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.7
         Compiling memoffset v0.9.0
         Compiling pyo3-ffi v0.19.1
         Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
         Compiling smallvec v1.10.0
         Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
         Compiling libmimalloc-sys v0.1.35
         Compiling pyo3 v0.19.1
         Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
         Compiling unindent v0.1.11
         Compiling indoc v1.0.9
         Compiling mimalloc v0.1.39
         Compiling pyo3-macros-backend v0.19.1
         Compiling pyo3-macros v0.19.1
         Compiling _pendulum v3.0.0 (/tmp/pip-install-5ojssvq9/pendulum_81f6c671fb0144cb9a4f88810bb66e4e/rust)
      error: this arithmetic operation will overflow
        --> src/helpers.rs:59:20
         |
      59 |         seconds += ((146_097 - 10957) * SECS_PER_DAY as usize) as isize;
         |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `135140_usize * 86400_usize`, which would overflow
         |
         = note: `#[deny(arithmetic_overflow)]` on by default

      error: could not compile `_pendulum` (lib) due to 1 previous error
       maturin failed
        Caused by: Failed to build a native library through cargo
        Caused by: Cargo build finished with "exit status: 101": `env -u CARGO PYO3_ENVIRONMENT_SIGNATURE="cpython-3.9-64bit" PYO3_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3" PYTHON_SYS_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/python3" "cargo" "rustc" "--message-format" "json-render-diagnostics" "--manifest-path" "/tmp/pip-install-5ojssvq9/pendulum_81f6c671fb0144cb9a4f88810bb66e4e/rust/Cargo.toml" "--release" "--lib" "--crate-type" "cdylib"`
      Error: command ['maturin', 'pep517', 'build-wheel', '-i', '/usr/bin/python3', '--compatibility', 'off'] returned non-zero exit status 1
      [end of output]

I tried workarounds such as installing pendulum 2.1.2 (which works without any problems) and using the only-if-needed upgrade strategy when installing azure-identity and msgraph-sdk, but they seem to require the 3.0.0 version of pendulum. Is there anything else I can do?
Pip Version is 24.0

any particular reason why you use a 32 bit OS? There would be whl files available for 64 bit OS

https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum/issues/784

The error arises, because the source code was written using datatypes that have different widths on 32-bit and 64-bit systems. You might get away with just changing that one line, but be prepared that you might have to make further changes as well.
src/helpers.rs:59:20
         |
      59 |         seconds += ((146_097 - 10957) * SECS_PER_DAY as usize) as isize;
         |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `135140_usize * 86400_usize`, which would overflow
         |

can be fixed with these steps:

Download the sourcecode from pypi, and extract it. For the sake of this answer, I will assume that it was extracted to /home/xx/pendulum

Open the file /home/xx/pendulum/rust/src/helpers.rs (mentioned in your error) and change line 59 from


seconds += ((146_097 - 10957) * SECS_PER_DAY as usize) as isize;

to
seconds += ((146_097 - 10957) * SECS_PER_DAY as u64) as i64;


Run pip install /home/xx/pendulum, which should now install your modified version of the library

